# CSS questions on grid systems, media queries, responsive web design

Tags: css, web

I am getting into web development, and am having a bit trouble with CSS. I am more of a C++/PHP guy, so this is a different world to me and it boggles my mind. My only problem with CSS is positioning objects. That is literally all I have problems with. I can easily reference complicated selectors, and lookup how to manipulate certain attributes....but positioning stops me dead in my tracks.

This is less of a question, and more of a call out to someone who knows what they doing. I am completely in love with the concept of responsive web design. I, however, have never dove into this personally (I use wordpress and responsive themes to handle visuals---while I write the content and plugins i need). **What exactly is involved in responsive web design?** I heard of grid systems alot, and it makes sense in my head. Is a grid system what makes a page layout change? How? Do i code my own or use a existing system?

What about media queries? I see examples of this, and its amazing to me (i understand zero of it lol). With media queries it seems like you would easily be able to create a responsive site...but where does the grid system come into play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use media queries and would recommend it for you also, here are some tutorials that I used when I was first learning responsive web design:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIz02qY5BRA 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fA1NW-T1QXc

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are new into this the best option is to try to use one of the frameworks around to try to achieve resposiveness. I will suggest have a look to [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

But to answer your question you usually use media tags in your CSS so you apply different styles based on the device being used to display the page. For example you can apply certain positions and sizes to your elements based on the screen width:

```
@media (min-width: 996px) {
    #yourelement {
       margin-left: 10px
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One resource I use on my website is Bootstrap. Bootstrap divides the page into 12 sections. For each `<div>` element, you can choose something similar to `.col-md-12`. This will tell the element to take up the entire width of the screen.

If you would like to make a page responsive to screen size, you would type something similar to `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3>` This is saying that on phones, `xs`, there will be one column. On tablets, `sm`, there will be two columns. On a standard screen and up, `md`, you will see 4 columns. You may also use `lg` for large screens.

Edit: To add to your second question about media queries, Bootstrap is based off of media queries. The follow shows what each size refers to:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

For more information about this, [here's a link to Bootstraps CSS section](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) that describes it.